# How to show Financial Report Output on Screen in OpenERP/Odoo 7

Tags: reporting, openerp-7, odoo, openerp-8

I have need where in our clients want to see the output of Financial Reports defined by them in OpenERP/Odoo 7 on Screen instead of out putting the same to PDF file which is the default behavior of OpenERP/Odoo?

All help is highly appreciated.

TIA

Yogi Yang